# Why less -F option does not work with -S option

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, less

While trying to improve output from `hg diff`, I noticed that `less`’s `-F` option does not work with its `-S` option. Why is that happening and how can I achieve the desired effect?

Here is an extract from `man`:

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
      Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be dis-
      played on the first screen.

   -S or --chop-long-lines
      Causes  lines  longer than the screen width to be chopped rather
      than folded.  That is, the portion of a long line that does  not
      fit  in  the  screen width is not shown.  The default is to fold
      long lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.
```

Tested on `less 444` and `less 436`.

### Explanation

I was mistaken in thinking that `-S` will cut excess bytes. Content goes to the right of the screen.

To achieve what I wanted I could just use `(...) | cut -b -80 | less -FSX`.

Comment: Do you really want to `-S`? If lines are longer than your output, the remainder will just be discarded, and you will lose information in your diff. Also, since I am passing by: I hope you use the `color` extension to get colorized diffs.

Comment: @Daniel: I feel that spanning long lines through multipe lines is a little bit messy. When using less if change does not show up in first 80 columns I can always temporarily expand my term window. :)

Comment: Without the color extension it gets very messy, but with it I have no issues. But we are all different human beings :-) .

Comment: @Daniel, I've never said that I do not use color extension. This question is about less, not ``hg``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me; `less -FS` exits immediately if the input can be printed on one screen without folding lines, and acts normally if scrolling (either to the right or down) is needed.

Comment: I've got less 444. Which version are you using?

Comment: @seler: less 443, but I've upgraded to 444 and it behaves the same.

Comment: I've been testing on Debian and Xubuntu under gnome terminal. What's your system and terminal?

Comment: Are you sure that in your testing file you've got lines longer than your terminals width?

Comment: @seler: Yes, sure. I generate the input with echo, like this `echo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | less -SF -`, where I enter enough `x`s that they wrap over and fill the whole line. The system is Debian sid, terminal is konsole. I tried it in the console, too, and saw slight difference in the behavior: in console, `less` prints the file when it would fit on one screen, under konsole, it doesn't (just exits). That is, however, dependent just on the `-F` parameter (doesn't depend on `-S`).

Comment: try with ``-X`` option

Comment: Heres a screencast showing how it behaves: http://tinypic.com/r/2s3k1/6

Comment: @seler: That's about what I see as well; when you overflowed the screen to the right, `less` didn't exit immediately. What do you not like about it?

Comment: I want it to behave as expected. Seems you've misunderstood me. :( Please edit your answer.

Comment: @seler: What is "expected"? When you read the manpage `Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.`, it pretty much describes what it does; in your last invocation, the data did *not* fit on a page.

Comment: Ok. You're right. I'm wrong. Sorry. :)

Comment: Using `less -FX` fixes the problem wherein less displays no output at all if it fits on a single screen.  But it creates another problem in that, if the output does not fit on a single screen, then after exiting `less`, all of the content that was displayed remains in the terminal buffer.  The `-X` causes the `termcap deinitialization string` to not be sent to the terminal.  What seems to be needed is a way to use `-X` conditionally with `-F`.